# Synchronous for loop in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

So let's say I have the following for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   Model.findOne({ _id = array[i].id}, function(err, found){
    //Some stuff
   });
}
```

How do I make this code work? Every time I run it I get `array[i] = undefined`because the mongo-db query is asynchronous and the loop has already iterated 5 times by the time the first query is even completed. How do I go about tackling this issue and waiting for the query to complete before going on to the next iteration?

Comment: Make it synchronous by assigning to another variable. var result = Model.findOne({ _id = array[i].id}, function(err, found){ //Some stuff
   });

Comment: If you used `Array.prototype.forEach`, the `item` would be the same in the callback as outside of it. Or, if you used the --harmony flag, and replaced `var i` with `let i`, it would also work. but with both of these solutions, i suspect you'll have further issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but addresses your problem.

I'd use an $in query and do the filtering all at once. 20 calls to the db is pretty slow compared to 1:

```
// grab your ids
var arrayIds = myArray.map(function(item) {
    return item._id;
});

// find all of them
Model.find({_id: {$in: arrayIds}}, function(error, foundItems) {

    if (error) {
        // error handle
    }

    // set up a map of the found ids
    var foundItemsMap = {};
    foundItems.forEach(function(item) {
        foundItemsMap[item._id] = true;
    });

    // pull out your items that haven't been created yet
    var newItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        var arrayItem = myArray[i];

        if ( foundItemsMap[arrayItem._id] ) {
            // this array item exists in the map of foundIds
            // so the item already exists in the database
        }
        else {
            // it doesn't exist, push it into the new array
            newItems.push(arrayItem);
        }
    }

    // now you have `newItems`, an array of objects that aren't in the database
});
```

Comment: You might need to throw some `.toString()`s for the _ids in there though, I'm not 100% sure

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and I didn't need to add .toString() to any ids.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to accomplish something like you want is using promises. You could use the library `q` to do this:

```
var Q = require('q');

function fetchOne(id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Model.findOne({ _id = id}, function(err, found){
        if(err) deferred.reject(err);
        else    deferred.resolve(found);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
function fetch(ids, action) {
    if(ids.length === 0) return;
    var id = ids.pop();
    fetchOne(id).then(function(model) {
        action(model);
        fetch(ids, action);
    });
}

fetch([1,2,3,4,5], function(model) { /* do something */ });
```

It is not the most beautiful implementation, but I'm sure you get the picture :)

Comment: I'm not sure though, why you would consider doing multiple `findOne`'s synchronized. Maybe you could elaborate to get an even better answer?

Comment: Come to think about it, maybe you could do this without promises.

Comment: I have a list of items that I have to add to the database, but first I have to check if they already exist.  I am making the multiple findOne calss, to check if they exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Emil! What's the alternative to promises?

Comment: Alright, then I will recommend two other options to look into. One is the simple improvement, where you find all the ids first with `find` and `$in`. That way you can fetch all docs from DB and then insert the missing. The better alternative is to use an upsert, which is a combined insert and update the will insert the document if missing and otherwise it will update it. This last solution is atomic, this you will avoid race conditions.

Comment: The alternative to promises I thought about is just doing it recursive, a bit like in my example in the answer, just skipping all the promise stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way, it could be a bit expensive but this how i did it. 
I think the trick is to pull all your data and then looking for an id match.

```
Model.find(function(err, data) {
    if (err) //handle it

    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; ij<data.length; j++) {
            if(data[j].id == array[i].id) {
               // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```